# username is not correct error i dont even know y please someone help me

Tags: c#

I keep getting a username is incorrect error this is for login i dont know why i desperatley need help, i did everything correct but still gives me errors what can i do

below is my code

```
protected void Button_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string checkuser = "select count(*) from [Table] where UserName=@UserName";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
    com.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NChar, 20).Value = TextBoxUserName.Text + "'";
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    //int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
    conn.Close();
    if (temp == 1)
    {
        conn.Open();

        string checkPasswordQuery = " select password from [Table] where UserName=@UserName";
        SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
        passComm.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = TextBoxUserName.Text;

        string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");

        if (password == TextBoxPassword.Text)
        {
            //declaring new session
            Session["New"] = TextBoxUserName.Text;
            Response.Write("PASSWORD IS CORRECT");

            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("PASSWORD IS NOT CORRECT");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("USERNAME IS NOT CORRECT");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your connection string value of `RegistrationConnectionString` in your config file?

Comment: I dont understand the question really, what do you mean by this sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add single quote at the end of the username.

Replace This:

```
com.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NChar, 20).Value = 
                                                TextBoxUserName.Text + "'";
                                                                      ^^^^^^
```

With This:

```
com.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NChar, 20).Value = TextBoxUserName.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also trim your parameters in both queries.

```
 string checkPasswordQuery = " select password from [Table] where Ltrim(Rtrim(UserName))=@UserName";
 SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
 passComm.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = TextBoxUserName.Text.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is case-sensitive, which may or may not be intended.

You believe you can use

"select count(*) from [Table] where Lower(UserName)=Lower(@UserName)"

MDSN Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174400.aspx

Comment: Not necessarily.  It would depend on the `COLLATION` being used.  I believe the default collation is case insensitive.